# Declaration of ArrayAccess:: must be compatible with ArrayAccess::($offset, $value)

Tags: php, slim

I'm developing a website via PHP Slim Framework and AngularJS. From one moment, to another every simple request gave me the following error:

> Fatal error: Declaration of ArrayAccess::�H� must be compatible with
>   ArrayAccess::($offset, $value) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\projectnamehere\backend\vendor\pimple\pimple\src\Pimple\Container.php
>   on line 39

The last modification was simply a GET endpoint for a table named street.

Route:

```
$app->get('/api/streets', \App\Controllers\StreetController::class . ':findAll');
```

Entity:

```
namespace App\Entities;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Street extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'street';

    protected $fillable = [
      'street'
    ];
}
```

And the controller:

```
namespace App\Controllers;


use App\Entities\Street;
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

class StreetController
{
    public function findAll(Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
        return Street::all()->toJson();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea about what the hell is going on?

Comment: what is �H� ? Looks like non UTF-8

Comment: No idea, my code doesn't have any kind of non utf-8 characters.

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php, the method that is incompatible is `abstract public void offsetSet ( mixed $offset , mixed $value )`

Comment: But it looks fine in Pimple! https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple/blob/master/src/Pimple/Container.php#L79

Comment: Which version of Pimple are you running?

Comment: Itt looks fine in my code too... (since it's in the vendor directory and never modified it :D )

`public function offsetSet($id, $value)`

Comment: sounds like a job for XDebug!

Comment: Wow. Restarting apache solved my problem... Thanks anyways.

Comment: hehe, no probs!